# Can the famo.us framework be used on Intel XDK?

Tags: intel-xdk, famo.us

Can the famo.us framework be used with Intel XDK?
Are there known issues when working with them together in order to build a hybrid app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be any issues using famous framework in [Intel XDK](http://xdk.intel.com). Any HTML5 framework will work in Intel XDK to develop, test and build hybrid app.

I just tried couple famous demo apps in Intel XDK and it all worked fine in emulator and to build apps:

[image]

[image]